# why am I getting this error, I tried to fix it, but failed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I'm trying to use "MessageEmbed" in my bot when someone says "*Staff" but, "MessageEmbed" is killing me and saying errors every time I try to fix it, I'd love some help :D. thanks

the Error:

> [image: Error Picture]

Code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();


const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const cmd = require("node-cmd");
const ms = require("ms");
const fs = require('fs');
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const canvas = require("canvas");
const convert = require("hh-mm-ss")
const fetchVideoInfo = require("youtube-info");
const simpleytapi = require('simple-youtube-api')
const util = require("util")
const gif = require("gif-search");
const jimp = require("jimp");
const guild = require('guild');
const hastebins = require('hastebin-gen');
const getYoutubeID = require('get-youtube-id');
const pretty = require("pretty-ms");
const moment = require('moment');
const request = require('request');
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');

app.listen(() => console.log("DwaCraft SayBot Starting...."));

const prefix = "*"//Prefix
const developers = ["612110791683866644","694996503324000378"] //Devs IDs
const dev1 = "612110791683866644"
const owner = "694996503324000378"
const dev3 = " "
const dev4 = " "


///help

      client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "help") {
        message.delete(5000)
        if(!message.channel.guild) return;
        const e = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#36393e')
        .setTitle('sent in DM')
     const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
         .setColor('#36393e')
    
         .setDescription(`
         \`\`\`Main Commands  :\`\`\`         

         - ${prefix}ping : To know the connection speed of the bot
 
         \`\`\`Admin Commands :\`\`\` 
         
         - ${prefix}say : make the bot say any thing


`)
   message.channel.send(e).then(m => m.delete(5000))
   message.author.sendEmbed(embed).catch(error => message.reply('**open your dm to allow me to send it**'))
   
   }
   });
  
//say embad

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  let command = message.content.split(" ")[0];
  command = command.slice(prefix.length);

  let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);

  if (command === "say") {
    if (!message.channel.guild)
      return message.channel
        .send("This is only for servers")
        .then(m => m.delete(5000));
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"))
      return message.channel.send("Unfortunately, you don't have the permission ADMINISTRATOR");
    message.delete();
    message.channel.sendMessage(args.join(" "));

    if (message == prefix + "say")
       message.channel.sendMessage("Please contain a message")
      .then(m => m.delete(3000));
  }
  if (command == "embed") {
    if (!message.channel.guild)
      return message.channel
        .send("This command is only for servers")
        .then(m => m.delete(5000));
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
      return message.channel.send("You don't have the permission to use this command.");
    let say = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setDescription(args.join("  "))
      .setColor(694996);
    message.channel.sendEmbed(say);
    message.delete();
    
    if (message == prefix + "embed")
       message.channel.sendMessage("Please contain a message")
      .then(m => m.delete(3000));
  }
});
client.on("ready", () =>{
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",  // Do not disturb is dnd
        game: {
            name: "DwaCraft.net",  // msg
            type: "PLAYING" // PLAYING, WATCHING LISTENING, STREAMING,
        }
    });
 });

 client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "setname")) {
    let args = message.content.split(" ");
    let botnameee = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!developers.includes(message.author.id))
      return message.channel.send(
        `** :x: Only Developers/Owners Can Use this Command ! :x: **`
      );
    if (!botnameee)
      return message.channel.send(
       `** :x: Please Provide the new name ! :x: **`
      );
    message.channel.send(`Changing to the new Name...`).then(me => {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Name.`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Name..`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Name...`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait.`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait..`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait...`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Done, Changed my name to *${botnameee}*!`);
      client.user.setUsername(`${botnameee}`);
    }, 12000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    });
  }
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "setavatar")) {
    let args = message.content.split(" ");
    let botnameee = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!developers.includes(message.author.id))
      return message.channel.send(
        `** :x: Only Developers/Owners Can Use this Command ! :x: **`
      );
    if (!botnameee)
      return message.channel.send(
        `** :x: Please Provide an avatar ! :x: **`
      );
    message.channel.send(`Changing The bot's Avatar...`).then(me => {
   setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Avatar.`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Avatar..`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Changing to the new Avatar...`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait.`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait..`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Please wait...`);
    }, 2000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      me.edit(`Done, Changed Avatar to *${botnameee}*!`);
      client.user.setAvatar(`${botnameee}`);
    }, 12000); //milliseconds, 100ms = 1s
    });
  }
});


client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "staff")) {
  const devs = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Staff')
      .setURL('https://dwacraft.tebex.io')
        .setAuthor('DwaCraft', 'https://imgur.com/a/nbIWI5n', 'https://dwacraft.tebex.io')
      .setDescription("\u200B")
      .setThumbnail('https://imgur.com/a/nbIWI5n')
      .addFields(
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B', inline: true },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '*STAFF*', inline: true },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B', inline: true },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
            { name: 'Owner', value: 'SirDevinci', inline: true },
            { name: 'Manager', value: 'GrowTaz', inline: true },
        { name: 'Developer', value: 'Hamoodiyt', inline: true },
        { name: 'Developer', value: 'Enkix', inline: true },
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('DwaCraft on top', 'https://imgur.com/a/nbIWI5n');

  message.channel.send(devs);
  }
});

client.login("TOKEN");
```

^^^
Btw I'm Not sure if the ERROR thing up there works...

Package.json file

```js
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "array-sort": "^1.0.0",
    "canvas": "^2.6.1",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "discord.js": "^11.3.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "get-youtube-id": "^1.0.1",
    "gif-search": "^2.1.0",
    "guild": "^1.2.2",
    "hastebin-gen": "^2.0.5",
    "hh-mm-ss": "^1.2.0",
    "jimp": "^0.14.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ms": "^2.1.2",
    "node-cmd": "^3.0.0",
    "pretty-ms": "^7.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "simple-youtube-api": "^5.2.1",
    "table": "^5.4.6",
    "util": "^0.12.3",
    "youtube-info": "^1.3.2",
    "ytdl-core": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

[image]

Note: If you can, please talk on Discord to me [ Hamoodiyt#4822 ]

Comment: What discord.js version are you using?

Comment: I'm using https://replit.com Hacker Plan, so it's probably last version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using discord.js v11, so you can't use `MessageEmbed()` and have to use `RichEmbed()`!

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work, Getting a new error, I'll make a new Answer to show the error.

Comment: @Hamoodiyoutube what error do you get

Comment: I added a new answer to show it, I'm not sure why it doesn't show up

Comment: @Hamoodiyoutube Define embed using `const devs = new Discord.MessageEmbed()`, also change `RichEmbed` to `MessageEmbed` in your embeds!

Comment: When I changed the other embeds into MessageEmbed they broke

Comment: @Hamoodiyoutube Then I think you are using discord.js v11 (Which means you have to use RichEmbed instead)

Comment: How to check the version tho ?

Comment: Your `package.json` file should contain all modules you are using and their versions

Comment: Added it to the answer
.

Comment: @Hamoodiyoutube yes, you are using d.js v11, so you can't use MessageEmbed and have to use RichEmbed instead

Comment: Oh, Ok, anyway thanks for trying to help !

Comment: Uhh, why is this happening ??

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXgbc.png 

I added // before all of the code, Now why is this happening ?

Comment: what happened ?', @MegaMix_Craft

Comment: Nvm, I'm just an idoit